# GetHttpContext() null while authenticating user in SignalR Hub

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to create and Sign-In a User using Asp.Net Identity within a SignalR Hub like so:

```
public string CreateUser(string username, string password)
{
    var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
    var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

    var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = username };
    IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, password);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var authenticationManager = Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { }, userIdentity);
        return "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        var authenticationManager = Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        return "Failed: "+result.Errors;
    }
}
```

But GetHttpContext() is always null, could someone kindly explain why?

What is the best way to call the SignIn method from within a Hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ancient question here, but a hub is an open channel of communication, so the process of using forms auth and identity like this won't work. There is no response to set headers on or ways to set cookies. You need a regular HTTP exchange for that.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, yeah figured that out the hard way. I ended up using an owin module that essentially does http basic auth - this was the recommended way to do it at the time any recommendations?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to auth over a persistent connection. It doesn't seem like there's any benefit in doing so.

Comment: The reason for using a hub over a persistent connection was because only Hubs offer Client to server cold RPC calls - please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: OK, but what does that have to do with auth? I mean, HTTP is stateless and usually you don't want open connections hanging out. The use case for SignalR is mostly for something server side to talk to the client/browser, which ordinarily wouldn't be listening.